# email is not working when email content has my own domain name

Tags: php, email

I am using simple php script for sending a mail , when I use my own domain name as email content like this

```
$message="Please visit us at https://myhouseinthecloud.com/";
mail($email,$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
```

then my email stops working and if I remove this link,as

```
 $message="Please visit us";
 mail($email,$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
```

then it works. I didn't get what is the problem. I h've problem only with this domain.

Comment: Goes to spam most probably

Comment: Check if your domain is blacklisted or not

Comment: I checked it, my domain is not blacklisted

Comment: it neither goes to inbox nor in spam folder

Answer (score 0):

Please try using a anchor tag like `<a href='https://myhouseinthecloud.com/'>Click Here</a>`
for more info:
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=416467

Answer (score 0):

it is server side problem. please check server smtp configurations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).